Definition of pullback of function between complex projective varieties
While reading through an algebraic geometry textbook, I have been struggling to pin down the definition of a morphism for complex projective varieties. According to the textbook, "a continuous map of topological spaces $f : X \rightarrow  Y$ is a morphism if every pullback of a regular function on Y is a regular function on X."
Setup:

When $X$ and $Y$ are varieties on complex projective spaces, i.e. $X = \mathcal{V}_{pr}(I) \in \mathbb{C}P^m, Y = \mathcal{V}_{pr}(J) \in \mathbb{C}P^n$ for some homogenous ideals $I, J$, a regular function $g$ on $Y$ is a function $g: \mathcal{V}(J) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Question:

Trying to pullback $g$, we obtain $g \circ f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Since the domain of this pullback is the projective variety $X$, how can the pullback possibly be regular, if regular functions on $X$ must have domain $\mathcal{V}(I)$?

